# Web API for SVN

Tags: svn, svn-api

I wish to pull change logs via some web API. Is such a thing possible? I'd rather not use an external library to wrap the calls.

e.g. `GET http://repo/?branch=123&revision=789` gets the changes to branch 123 in revision 789.

(The major thing is that I don't want to have to check out an entire branch locally to view its changes.)

Comment: Please, choose btw one of the answer below to be your prefered answer, it will help people.

Answer (score 2):

`svn log` takes both a URL and revision as parameters.

```
svn log http://repo/PATH_TO_BRANCH_123 -r 789
```

See [`svn help log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) for more.

Subversion has no internal knowledge of branches - they're copies, there is nothing special about them. You could call your branches directory "forks" or "spoons" and it would work identically.

Answer (score 1):

SVN uses WebDAV as the protocol to communicate with clients in HTTP/HTTPS. It seems that the SVNKit guys have this kind of API in JAVA (server side). I think you can write a JavaScript lib to deal with it, i did not found one.

http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/opensource/excerpts/9780596510336/webdav-and-autoversioning.html